# date edit using guid key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used `guid` as primary key for my table.

```
namespace entities
{
    public class position 
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid positionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

From my view page, I am sending this `positionId` as string and then to the method `GetById`

How to use the Guid for data edit? I am trying to do:

```
public JsonResult GetById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = (from z in db.positions
                            where z.positionId == id
                            select z).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

This query is showing error as: `Operator == can not be applied to operands of type string and guid.`
How to convert this string id to type Guid?

Comment: First, parse the `id` into a Guid. Second, you're loading a single item by its primary key. You could use `Find` instead of writing a query, ie `return db.positions.Find(Guid.Parse(id))`. If you don't want that, use `FirstOrDefault` to returns a single result ie `db.Positions.FirstOrDefault(z=>z.positionId==Guid.Parse(id))`.

Comment: BTW you should change the parameter type to `Guid` so you won't have to parse the string. That `id` can't be anything other than a Guid after all

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just use Guid instead of string?
Anyway to convert a string to Guid you should use the [Guid.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse?view=net-6.0) method

Answer (score 0):

By following Kvble answer:

```
public JsonResult GetById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = (from z in db.positions
                            where z.positionId == Guid.Parse(id);
                            select z).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```